# Regular expression issue with lookbehind and lookahead

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to create a regex that takes all the content from `<div class="entrytext">` to the first `</p>` next to this div class.

At the moment this is what I have:

```
(?<=<div class="entrytext">.*<p>).*(?></p>)
```

Is going well cause all the code above this div is not matching, but the issue that I'm having is after this `<div>` there are a lots of `</p>` in the document.

What I would like is to take all the content next this div but until the first `</p>` found.

Could you give me a hand? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What programming language? Also, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Most regex parsers don't allow for variable length lookbehinds
2. You would need non-greedy operators (A `?` after your `*`)
   `(?<=<div class="entrytext">.*?<p>).*?(?></p>)`
3. Regex is (surprisingly for once) the tool for this job, but still look into html parsers, whatever you are doing that needs this probably would benefit from one.

Comment: @Jose3d: Make sure you understand _why_ it works. Look up 'greedy' and 'non-greedy' in the documentation or peruse http://www.regular-expressions.info

Comment: @sehe, why don't you tell him `?` is a quantifier as well as a quantifier modifier.

Comment: I think i got it, "?" takes the less possible while other quantifiers takes as much as possible. Thanks